# QuickBooks Online oAuth tokens

Tags: oauth, quickbooks

I am developing a .NET web app through which users will connect to QuickBooks Online using the "Connect to QuickBooks" button. The oAuth authentication flow works fine when connecting to QBO. When oAuth response is returned I am storing the oAuth token in the database. My questions are

1. How to use the oAuth token next time the user logs into the application so that the end user does not have to reconnect to QuickBooks Online.
2. What happens when the tokens expire and how that should be handled ? Please help.